# My Flask app returns an unexpected syntax error

Tags: python, sql, runtime-error, syntax-error, backend

I'm basically building a secured online diary application with Flask. However my Python source code returns a syntax error when I try to test the app. I can't detect what's wrong with the syntax. Your help will be appreciated.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the error. And here's my SQL database's schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
username TEXT NOT NULL,
hash TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username ON users (username);

CREATE TABLE diaries (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
title TEXT NOT NULL,
description TEXT NOT NULL,
img_url TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

[image: screenshot]

**New error: unsupported value**

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is INSERT statement that causes error.

Well, not the insert itself but the way you're using it.

Values should be passed as a tuple (values between "(" and ")")

So, you need to update db.execute line with something like that

```
db.execute("insert into table_name(col1, col2) values(?, ?)", (col1_val, col2_val))
```

UPD. regarding the error on second screenshot.

db.execute("Select...) does not return a value but a set of values.

So, you might wanted to use fetchone() as in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

```
res = cur.execute('SELECT count(rowid) FROM stocks') # gets you set records
print(res.fetchone()) # get first record
```

Anyway, check the docs I provided you link to with.

Comment: Thanks! I think this fixed **that** error, however now I encounter another error: unsupported value [ ]. I edited my question to add a new screenshot. Can you please help? @ekochergin

Comment: Hi @RumeysaGelgi. check updated answer please